# Spring Framework application high memory usage on start up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-restcontroller, spring-mongodb

I have wrote REST APIs in java Spring Framework.

I have referred [this](https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth) github project and my project structure is very similar to this.

My application contains Spring Boot, Spring Security, Spring Security OAuth, Spring Data JPA and Spring mongodb.

I have observed that on start, the application consumes more than 100MB and increases 2MB on each URL request. Also mongodb connection is not closed automatically after some timeout.

I am not able to figure out this application start up memory usage. (is this because of spring boot or spring security or any other lib ?)

Is there any other best java framework for quick REST API development with Security, OAuth and MongoDB feature.

I want memory optimized REST APIs.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are lots of places where memory will be used if it's available, for example due to in-memory caching that improves performance. As a result, analysis of memory usage isn't very meaningful without also knowing how the JVM has been configured. This blog post may be of interest: https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance